# Is it possible to query via bounding box in the Google Maps Static API?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api, c++, qt

We have a `Qt` program written in `C++` to request `wms` tiles and display them. This works fine.

Now we want to display imaginery from `Google Maps` and due to some restrictions in our program, we can't use javascript and we have to directly manage the url. For example, in the wms case:

```
www.idee.es/wms/PNOA-MR/PNOA-MR?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&FORMAT=image/jpeg&CRS=epsg:32629&LAYERS=PNOA-MR&STYLES=&REQUEST=GetMap&EXCEPTIONS=INIMAGE&TRANSPARENT=TRUE&WIDTH=256&HEIGHT=256&BBOX=621921.34,4794536.07,622951.58,4801396.70
```

So I think the right choice for `Google Maps` would be the static API.

Now, reading it I didn't find anything regarding querying by bounding box. Only querying via a center and a zoom level.

Is that the only way to retrieve an image? Wouldn't it possible to query with a bounding box without specifying a center and the zoom level and retrieve an image representing that extension? Just like with the `wms` case before.

**NOTE:** I would like and url example if possible. We can't use `javascript` for this.

Answer (score 7):

Google Static map api requires centre,lat/lng and pixel size as well as zoom level

This is a non-JavaScript version (but python) for working out the pixel dimensions.

You will need to modify to suit your needs but the key point is that it contains

```
CalculateBoundsZoomLevel
```

Which take a cluster of points and calculate the zoom level and centre of the map required.

> ```
> This method is used to take in a bounding box (southwest and northeast
> bounds of the map view we want) and a map size and it will return us a zoom
> level for our map.  We use this because if we take the bottom left and
> upper right on the map we want to show, and calculate what pixels they
> would be on the map for a given zoom level, then we can see how many pixels
> it will take to display the map at this zoom level.  If our map size is
> within this many pixels, then we have the right zoom level.
> ```

http://code.google.com/p/google-ajax-examples/source/browse/trunk/nonjslocalsearch/localSearch.py

Comment: Very nice! I can't upvote you, though! :(

Comment: You need a rep of 15 to upvote - so you need two more users to upvote your good question first.

Comment: The link to code.google.com no longer works. It appears that this is a clone (?) of the original code, though: https://github.com/gbrammer/threedhst/blob/master/threedhst/gmap.py

Comment: Original link is dead, here's the archive: https://web.archive.org/web/20141005190719/http://code.google.com/p/google-ajax-examples/source/browse/trunk/nonjslocalsearch/localSearch.py